# PhpStorm How to correctly configure upload shortcut?

Tags: ftp, upload, phpstorm

I finally bought the PhpStorm licence. Been using it for two years and, since their doing a great job, I had to play the game and be honest.

Now I'm faced with a problem, previously I had the perfect configuration that I don't have anymore.
Every project is linked to a ftp remote host. When I edited a file locally and save with ctrl + S, it saved the file locally without uploading it.
To upload I configured the explicit save on CTRL + Maj + S (In tools > Deployment > Option).
It was perfect!

With the new version, I can't find a way to do that. I tried updating the shortcut in the settings but it always stays "On explicit save action (Ctrl + S)".

I'm missing something and it's driving me crazy... (loosing all my ftp configuration in the update did not help).

Comment: what is `Maj` ?

Comment: I think you want something like this. First press ctrl + shift + a (en Keyboard) type `keymap`, select the one that says `settings>keymap`, then here you can do your own copy of the keymaps and in the search box search for `upload to..` under deployment, then you can bind that to whatever you want.

Comment: Some screenshots that would give some explanation on what you have configured and how are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

That was actually a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-21962
The behavior you're currently experiencing is expected.

You can assign Ctrl+S to Other | Save Document action in Keymap - this would save currently opened file only and wouldn't trigger auto-upload.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. I've set Ctrl + Shift + S for "File>Save all" and "Strl + S" for "Other>Save Document" but in the Tools>Deployment>Options I can't select one or the other for the "Upload changed files automatically to the defaut server", the dropdown only have "Always", "On explicit save action (Ctrl+Shift+S, Ctrl+S)", "Never".

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. You can submit a corresponding feature request to have an option to not upload the file on "Save document" action: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes